# Dynamically detect when two processors are ready to communicate in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I have an MPI program where each processor does the following:

- Do expensive operation.
- If I need to store anything remotely (could be on any other processor), queue a request for it in a buffer and continue.
- If buffer gets full enter comm phase.

In the comm phase, the processor with the full buffer should send away some of its buffered information, then return to "expensive operation".  Of course, this can't happen until at least two processors have entered the comm phase and can execute MPI commands.

Currently I'm dealing with this by pausing until ALL processors enter the comm phase, then doing something like,

```
MPI_Allgather(Num_send_local,NTask,MPI_INT,Num_send_global,NTask,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

where Num_send_local is an array of length NTask containing the number of things to send to each task (so Num_send_global is then NTask*NTask).

This works, but can often result in a lot of wasted resources as processors that could be communicating with one another sit around waiting until everyone is ready to send.

Really what I want to happen is for communication to happen as soon as two processors enter the comm phase, but I'm having trouble implementing it.  I've tried the following:

```
//Tell everyone I'm in the comm phase now
for(i=0;i<NTask;i++)
{
  if(Task==i)
    continue;
  MPI_Isend(&Num_send_local[i],1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request[i]);
}
MPI_Recv(&local,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
remote_partner = status.MPI_SOURCE;
//Do stuff between Task and remote_partner...
```

But this runs into problems where remote_partner receives someone else's send request instead of Task's.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the scale of your application and as always, measuring performance is the key (when you have at least some working version). You could try a master-slave approach, where one process handles distributing work to idle slave processes. Stackoverflow and the greater Internet have lots of resources on implementing a master-slave parallel program.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for can be found in this rather lengthy example [here](http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/one-step/ezstart.php) of a master-slave model. When the work on a slave is finished, a slave will send a result and the master knowns to send another round of work to the slave.